# Error after changing package name

Tags: android, google-maps, package-name

I change my package name by using refactor option . then i made the reacquired changes in manifest file . then i made changes when imports of previous packages is done . But now all reference are giving erorrs. R cannot be resolved to a variable

I have have checked string.xml and all the layout files?
How to over come this problem?  I have google maps in my package too.

Comment: try cleaning your project.

Comment: already tried things like cleaning rebuliding properly adding libs but still no luck

Comment: maybe you have errors, so it doesn't fully build.

Comment: @Gintas_ : error is reference are giving erorrs. R cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: do you have any errors in resources folder, like in layout file?